# Typescript and ImmutableJS.set()

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I want to have an ImmutableJS Map which has to have always defined some properties:

```
interface MyImmutableMap extends Immutable.Map<string, any> {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c?: string;
}
```

I have a function which edits the map:

```
function myFunction(myMap: MyImmutableMap, flag: boolean, value: number): MyImmutableMap {
  if (flag) {
     return myMap
       .set('a', value);
  }

  return myMap;
}
```

The second return is ok, because it returns the same thing I received, therefore an *MyImmutableMap*.

Unfortunately the *set()* doesn't work, because its return type is a Map and not the type of *myMap*.

This is the error:

> Type 'Map' is not assignable to type 'MyImmutableMap'.
>   Property 'a' is missing in type 'Map'.

There is any way to go around this?

Comment: Object *properties* and map *entries* are not the same thing. Which one do you need?

Comment: @TamasHegedus indeed *entries* of the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following interface:

```
interface MyImmutableMap extends Immutable.Map<string, any> {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c?: string;
}
```

Defines an instance of `Immutable.Map` which also has the `a`, `b` and `c` **properties**:

```
let m: MyImmutableMap;
m.a = 4;
m.b = 6;
m.c = "str";
```

You cannot control the map key/values like that.

You can do this:

```
type MyImmutableMap = Immutable.Map<string, any> & {
    set(name: "a", value: number);
    get(name: "a"): number;

    set(name: "b", value: number);
    get(name: "b"): number;

    set(name: "c", value: string);
    get(name: "c"): string | undefined;
}
```

---

#### Edit

You can "override" the default `set` like so:

```
type MyImmutableMap = Immutable.Map<string, any> & {
    set(name: "a", value: number);
    set(name: "a", value: any): void
    get(name: "a"): number;

    set(name: "b", value: number);
    set(name: "b", value: any): void
    get(name: "b"): number;

    set(name: "c", value: string);
    set(name: "c", value: any): void
    get(name: "c"): string | undefined;
}
```

Then:

```
return myMap
    .set('c', 45);
}
```

Results in:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Map'

It's not the best error message for this case, it's still restricted.

Comment: Good idea, but in this way I do not have typecheck on the value of `set`, because the generic `set(key: K, value: V)` makes any value acceptable for any key. Do you have an idea to disable that behavior?

Comment: Shouldn't be `set(name: "b", value: any): void`?

Comment: @rpadovani Right, my bad. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have primitive values, you can also use [`Record`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record)s instead of a `Map`.

Sadly, the typings for *immutable.js* aren't that good and I am not sure if they are actively maintained by the authors (because the typings are part of the repo and not `@types`).

We had a similar issue and used *type assertions* to overwrite the `Map` with a "better" version:

```
declare function Immutable<T>(o: T): Immutable<T>;
interface Immutable<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K];
  set<S>(o: S): Immutable<T & S>;
}

const alice = Immutable({ name: 'Alice', age: 29 });
alice.get('name');      // Ok, returns a `string`
alice.get('age');       // Ok, returns a `number`
alice.get('lastName');  // Error: Argument of type '"lastName"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age"'.

const aliceSmith = alice.set({ lastName: 'Smith' });
aliceSmith.get('name');     // Ok, returns a `string`
aliceSmith.get('age');      // Ok, returns a `number`
aliceSmith.get('lastName'); // Ok, returns `string`
```

Since the `set` of *immutable.js* is something like `set(key:string, value:any)` you would need to use a generic to help the compiler:

```
declare function Immutable<T>(o: T): Immutable<T>;
interface Immutable<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K];
  set<S>(key:string, value:any): Immutable<T & S>;
}

const alice = Immutable({ name: 'Alice', age: 29 });
alice.get('name');      // Ok, returns a `string`
alice.get('age');       // Ok, returns a `number`
alice.get('lastName');  // Error: Argument of type '"lastName"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age"'.

const aliceSmith = alice.set<{ 'lastName':string }>('lastName', 'Smith');
aliceSmith.get('name');     // Ok, returns a `string`
aliceSmith.get('age');      // Ok, returns a `number`
aliceSmith.get('lastName'); // Ok, returns `string`
```

[Here is a link to the playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20function%20Immutable%3CT%3E(o%3A%20T)%3A%20Immutable%3CT%3E%3B%0Ainterface%20Immutable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20get%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(name%3A%20K)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%3B%0A%20%20set%3CS%3E(key%3Astring%2C%20value%3Aany)%3A%20Immutable%3CT%20%26%20S%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20alice%20%3D%20Immutable(%7B%20name%3A%20'Alice'%2C%20age%3A%2029%20%7D)%3B%0Aalice.get('name')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60string%60%0Aalice.get('age')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60number%60%0Aalice.get('lastName')%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%22lastName%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'%22name%22%20%7C%20%22age%22'.%0A%0Aconst%20aliceSmith%20%3D%20alice.set%3C%7B%20'lastName'%3Astring%20%7D%3E('lastName'%2C%20'Smith')%3B%0AaliceSmith.get('name')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60string%60%0AaliceSmith.get('age')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60number%60%0AaliceSmith.get('lastName')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20%60string%60)

Comment: My god, static typing is getting out of hand! What will happen if somebody sets a key with a simple string type and not a literal type?

Comment: Oh I see, you cannot do that.

Comment: AFAIK currently TypeScript can not infer this correctly . But you can change the `set` signature and use a generic. I'll update my question.